# Gradle seems to overrwrite ndk build arguments while adding product flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android project where the build.gradle looks like this:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.test"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        // Specifies the ABI configurations of your native
        // libraries Gradle should build and package with your APK.
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            targets "test_app"
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

productFlavors {
    general {
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                arguments "LOCAL_CFLAGS+=-std=c++11"
                arguments "LOCAL_CFLAGS+=-DMODE_GENERAL"
            }
        }
    }

    full {
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                arguments "LOCAL_CFLAGS+=-std=c++11"
                arguments "LOCAL_CFLAGS+=-DMODE_FULL"
            }
        }
    }
}

externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/cpp/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

}

My Android.mk in `path 'src/main/cpp/Android.mk'` already includes `LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c++11` and it builds fine if I don't have any product flavors. However, if I do have the product flavors then I have to include `arguments "LOCAL_CFLAGS+=-std=c++11"` to make it build. I am wondering if there is any way to avoid this as I feel I should only need to include extra args which are not mentioned in the `Android.mk`.

Comment: It is true that the gradle plugin overrides many settings of your NDK build, that's why **cFlags**, **abiFilter** and, finally, **arguments** have been introduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of the problematic behavior is not gradle, but that you set `LOCAL_CFLAGS` (a make variable) on make's command line. The rules of gnu make which runs under the hood of **ndk-build**, state that this "locks" the variable, and whatever you set in makefile has no effect. Make introduces a special [**`override`** directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html), but it cannot be used in ndk-build for `LOCAL_CFLAGS`.

You are not supposed to override `LOCAL_CFLAGS` from outside a local module; you should use `APP_CFLAGS` in Application.mk or as **ndk-build** command line arguments.

It is not a good idea to set `(whatever)_CFLAGS=-std=c++11` because these flags will be passed both to C++ and C compilers. This setting belongs to `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS` and her kin.

With gradle plugin, you can use **cFlags** and **cppFlags**, as shown in the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#link-gradle) - better than general-purpose **arguments**, *e.g.*:

```
productFlavors {
  full { 
    externalNativeBuild {
      ndkBuild {
        cFlags "-DMODE_FULL"
        cppFlags "-fexceptions"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will try this.